# How to calculate 28 day mortality?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks, classification, survival

I have a **retrospective EHR database** from a hospital and I would like to build an ML model to predict whether a patient will die within 28 days or not (from discharge/some time point T)

Can I check with you on the below steps?

a) Let's say I have a sample of 5000 patients

b) I choose training data as 3500 patients

c) For these 3500 patients, I extract the required variables and their values till time "T"

d) And now for training data, we need labels, So I calculate using a python script whether this person has died within 28 days from time "t" (because I have all their data. I can find the difference between his discharge date and death date)

e) If yes, I will label it as "1" else "0"

f) I build a supervised learning model using logistic regression

Now comes the challenging part (for me atleast)

g) I would like to apply this model on the unseen set of 1500 patients

h) I extract the same variables as training data

i) Now I apply the model to this unseen data of 1500 patients

k) But the problem is this will only give whether the patient will die or not. **How can I know whether
he will die or not in the 28 days?**

How can I incorporate this time component here.

Can somebody help me with this by providing easy to understand steps and which algorithm to use please?

Comment: Why not do survival analysis?

Comment: @DWin - Can survival analysis help in prediction as well? Sorry, not done much with survival analysis before...will read up online... Any other ML algorithms that can help?

Comment: Indeed survival analysis can predict. There are many flavors of survival analysis. The survival package in R is a "recommended package, but there are also alternatives. I use both `survival` and `rms`. There's a well supported `eha` (event history analysis) and more recently the `flexsurv` package has become available. There is also a random survival forest package if you wnat to stay on the "data science" side of mythology (ooops, that was what my spell-chucker offered and it amused me)  and don't want to stray into "real statistics".

Comment: LSTMs can work for such problems?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @DWin says in a comment, this is a standard application of survival analysis. That has the advantage of evaluating not only event occurrence but also the times to events.

If you do proceed with your train/test split (even 5000 patients [might not be enough](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64436/28500) for that to be reliable; model evaluation by resampling might be better) you say that you have time-to-event data. In that case, even with an all-or-none logistic regression model, you can evaluate 28-day mortality by ignoring deaths that occur after 28 days from your start time.

The [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) in R, also noted by @DWin, provides a well developed infrastructure for combining survival analysis with resampling-based model validation and calibration, and providing predictions for specified combinations of covariate values. There's no reason why the approaches used there can't be extended to analysis with more of a "machine-learning" or "data-science" flavor. Just be aware that models provided by those latter approaches can be harder for mere human beings to interpret.

Comment: Hi @EdM - One quick question. I was reading this paper https://translational-medicine.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12967-020-02620-5   which tackles a similar objective as mine. Here I see they haven't used Survival analysis. But can time to event analysis be done using regular classification algorithms? Its just that they have derived the labels as "1" and "0" based on 30 day interval. Can help me please with this?

Comment: @TheGreat it's certainly OK to focus only on things like 28-day or 30-day mortality if you don't care about the actual times to events. If you do care about times to events, it's possible to use methods like those in your cited paper to evaluate survival models, too. For example, the [R `xgboost` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=xgboost) allows for Cox and accelerated failure time survival models. Your choice comes down to whether or not you care about times to survival or only about yes/no survival up to a particular cutoff time.

Comment: Hi @EdM - Q1) Am a bit confused. Isn't focusing on things like 28-day or 30-day mortality called `Time to Event` analysis? Because based on your comment - `it's certainly OK to focus only on things like 28-day or 30-day mortality if you don't care about the actual times to events`, am I incorrect to understand that predicting 28 day or 30 day mortality is Time to event analysis? May I know why isn't that called as 'Time to event' analysis

Comment: Would you mind to help a noob like me to understand the difference/elaborate your comment  - `Your choice comes down to whether or not you care about times to survival or only about yes/no survival up to a particular cutoff time` with an example please? I thought both that you mentioned are time to event analysis and there is no difference between them. But looks like there is some difference

Comment: @TheGreat usually “time-to-event” analysis refers to determining how long it takes until an event. The output can be a plot of survival probability (I.e., no event) as a continuous function of time. When one examines things like 30-day mortality, the output is just what fraction of cases had the event through 30 days, regardless of how early or late the events might have happened in that time frame. That’s not normally called “time-to-event” analysis; if you want to make a distinction I suppose you could call that “events-up-to-time” analysis, although that’s not standard terminology

Comment: So am I right to understand that for problems like 28 day mortality or 60 day mortality, we don't really have to use `survival::Cox` objective function in Xgboost model..Because here it is still a normal classification problem. But labels are derived based on the time interval of 30 or 60 days and whatever prediction that we make using classification algorithm is also assumed to be of within 30 or 60 days.. Am I right?

Comment: Let's say for ex: I have a problem like predict the time taken to develop complications from the time of the first diagnosis, then here I will definitely have to use `survival::cox` objective function. Am I right? Because here we are really looking at `time to event` analysis?

Comment: @TheGreat yes, you have it right. If it's just survival up to some time, without reference to the actual time during that interval, then it's a classification (better, event-probability) task. If you want to model the actual time until an event, then it's a survival model. Besides `survival:cox`, the R implementation of `xgboost` (at least) also provides an accelerated-failure-time objective function (`survival:aft`) for survival models.

Comment: Thanks @EdM for patiently answering all my questions. Much appreciated